# How to delay background image on load

Tags: jquery, css, delay, fadein

I know how to delay an element on load, but I have a weird request from a client. They want the background image to load 5 seconds after the page loads. I'm new to js, thought I could do it easily, but it's not working out.

I've tried this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#primary .bcg').css( "background", "url(folder/path", function(){
        $(this).delay(5000).fadeIn(400)
        });
});
```

and this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#primary .bcg').delay(5000).fadeIn(400, function() {
           $('this').css( "background", "url(folder/path")
    });
});
```

Both to no avail. Is there a way to make this happen? Or rather a way for a novice to make it happen?

css:

```
#primary .bcg {
    background: none;
    background-attachment: fixed;
    background-position: center center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;

}
```

Much thanks for any help!

Comment: you have #Primary and #primary. Make them the same case

Answer (score 3):

You can do it like this using setTimeout as"

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   setTimeout(function(){
       $('#Primary .bcg').css('background', 'url(folder/path)');
   }, 5000);    // Delay for 5 seconds
});
```

Comment: Thanks, not sure if I'm doing something wrong, but when I use the block of code above, the background image loads immediately. The CSS is changing from `background: none` to `background: url(folder/path)`, but there is no delay.

Answer (score 1):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   setTimeout(function(){
       $('#Primary .bcg').css('background', 'url(folder/path)');
   }, 10000);    
});
```

You can use set time time out but you will not get the fadeIn effect with this . or you can

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#Primary .bcg').fadeOut(function() {
     $('#Primary .bcg').css({background : url('folder/path') });
    $('#Primary .bcg').fadeIn(300);
  }, 300);
})
```

Comment: Thanks, As for the first example; not sure if I'm doing something wrong, but when I use the block of code above, the background image loads immediately. The CSS is changing from background: none to background: url(folder/path), but there is no delay.

As for the 2nd example; if I’m not mistaken, I would have to set the opacity of the element in CSS and that would make the whole element `#primary .bcg` fadeIn and fadeOut, not just the background image, correct?